# CSS Animation not working in IE (All versions)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, animation

I have 4 frames of copy that fade in and  fade out. They work fine on all browsers apart from IE.

**HTML**

```
    <body>
    <div class="background">
        <!--[if lt IE 11]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <div id="banner">
            <div class="elements">
                <div class="logo"></div>

                        <div class="frame" id="frame-1"></div>
                        <div class="frame" id="frame-2"></div>
                        <div class="frame" id="tick-1"></div>
                        <div class="frame" id="tick-2"></div>
                        <div class="frame" id="frame-3"></div>                      
                        <div class="frame" id="frame-4"></div>
                        <div class="frame" id="medium"></div>
                        <div class="frame" id="small"></div>
                        <div class="frame" id="frame-5">
                            <img src="styles/card.png" class="card"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="frame" id="frame-6">
                            <img src="styles/cta.png" class="cta"/>
                        </div>




                    <div class="faces">
                            <div class="front-1">
                                <img src="images/face-01.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="back-1">
                                <img src="images/face-02.jpg">
                            </div> 
                            <div class="front-2">
                                <img src="images/face-03.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="back-2">
                                <img src="images/face-04.jpg">
                            </div> 

                            <div class="front-3">
                                <img src="images/face-17.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="back-3">
                                <img src="images/face-06.jpg">
                            </div> 
                            <div class="front-4">
                                <img src="images/face-07.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="front-5">
                               <img src="images/face-09.jpg">
                            </div>


                            <div class="front-6">
                                <img src="images/face-11.jpg">
                            </div>


                            <div class="front-7">
                                <img src="images/face-13.jpg">
                            </div>

                      </div>

              </div>
          </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>

@-moz-keyframes spin2 { 100% {opacity:1; -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin2 { 100% {opacity:1; -webkit-transform:rotateY(-180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0 0; transform-origin:100% 0 0; } }
@keyframes spin2 { 100% {opacity:1; transform:rotateY(-180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0 0; transform-origin:100% 0 0; } }

@-moz-keyframes spin3 { 100% { opacity:1; transform:rotateX(-180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:0 100% 0; transform-origin:0 100% 0; } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin3 { 100% { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:rotateX(-180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:0 100% 0; transform-origin:0 100% 0; } }
@keyframes spin3 { 100% { opacity:1; transform:rotateX(-180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:0 100% 0; transform-origin: 0 100% 0; } }

@-moz-keyframes spin5 { 100% { opacity:1; transform:rotateX(180deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 100% 0; transform-origin:100% 0 0 } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin5 { 100% { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:0 0 100% 0; transform-origin:0 0 100% 0; } }
@keyframes spin5 { 100% { opacity:1; transform:rotateX(180deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 100% 0  ; transform-origin: 0 0 100% 0; } } 


@-moz-keyframes spin4 { 100% {opacity:1; -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin4 { 100% {opacity:1; -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100% 0; transform-origin:0 100% 0; } }
@keyframes spin4 { 100% {opacity:1; transform:rotateY(180deg); -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0 0; transform-origin:0 100% 0; } }



.faces {
  -webkit-animation:faces-end 0.5s 16s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:faces-end 0.5s 16s linear forwards;
  animation:faces-end 0.5s 16s linear forwards; 
}


.frame#frame-1 {
  opacity: 1 \9; /*just in case ie*/

  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s 0.1s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 5s 1 linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s 0.1s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 5s 1 linear forwards;
  -o-animation: fadein 0.5s 0.1s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 5s 1 linear forwards;
  animation: fadein 0.5s 0.1s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 5s 1 linear forwards;

  font-family:'barclaycard_co_ltregular',verdana,sans-serif;
}

.frame#frame-2 {
  opacity: 1 \9; /*just in case ie*/

  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s 5.5s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 10.5s 1 linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s 5.5s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 10.5s 1 linear forwards;
  -o-animation: fadein 0.5s 5.5s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 10.5s 1 linear forwards;
  animation: fadein 0.5s 5.5s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 10.5s 1 linear forwards;

  font-family:'barclaycard_co_ltregular',verdana,sans-serif;
}

.frame#tick-1 {
  opacity: 1 \9; /*just in case ie*/

  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s 5.5s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 10.5s 1 linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s 5.5s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 10.5s 1 linear forwards;
  -o-animation: fadein 0.5s 5.5s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 10.5s 1 linear forwards;
  animation: fadein 0.5s 5.5s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 10.5s 1 linear forwards;

  font-family:'barclaycard_co_ltregular',verdana,sans-serif;
}

.frame#tick-2 {
  opacity: 1 \9; /*just in case ie*/

  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s 11s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 1s 16s 1 linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s 11s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 16s 1 linear forwards;
  -o-animation: fadein 0.5s 11s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 16s 1 linear forwards;
  animation: fadein 0.5s 11s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 16s 1 linear forwards;

  font-family:'barclaycard_co_ltregular',verdana,sans-serif;

}

.frame#frame-3 {
  opacity: 1 \9; /*just in case ie*/

  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s 11s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 1s 16s 1 linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s 11s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 16s 1 linear forwards;
  -o-animation: fadein 0.5s 11s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 16s 1 linear forwards;
  animation: fadein 0.5s 11s 1 linear forwards, fadeout 0.5s 16s 1 linear forwards;

  font-family:'barclaycard_co_ltregular',verdana,sans-serif;
}
```

Can't see anything wrong with the CSS, is this just something IE cannot handle?

Can't see anything wrong with the CSS, is this just something IE cannot handle?

Can't see anything wrong with the CSS, is this just something IE cannot handle?

Comment: It looks fine in IE 11 to me.

Comment: Now I understand, I thought you were talking about the photos.

Comment: I still don't see any difference, but I had to disable a Tracking Protection List (TPL) that I had installed on my IE.  The TPL was blocking the download of the script from "flashtalking.com".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add -ms- prefixes to your animation.

```
-ms-animation:spin2 0.5s 1.9s linear forwards;
```

Also, consider using transition properties instead of keyframe animations where you can, as they are much more widely supported.

Comment: This can't be the solution because IE 10+ (which are the only versions that support CSS animations at all) support unprefixed keyframes animations.

Comment: @JosiahKeller what do you suggest?